# How to set Youtube subtitles/close captions to be right alignment?

Tags: youtube, text-alignment, subtitle, video-subtitles

When I watch like tutorial in Youtube which the content mostly (if any explanation on white board or on a computer monitor) is in (our) left side. The Youtube subtitles also we may put ***left alignment*** or ***center***, but not ***right alignment*** (borrowing the terminologies used by Microsoft Word). Sometimes, the subtitle overlap the content of the tutorial, quiet disturbing. So, is it possible to align the subtitle right? Before I post this question, I have rechecked if any way to do it on Youtube.

Edit: [here](https://youtu.be/iBxK9LZDDog) is an example that the subtitle overlapping the tutorial.

Comment: [edit] the question and add the URL of the video(s) you've watched that has the subtitles as you described.